# String array index to string

Tags: java, string, random

I'm trying to change a random index from a string array and put it in a `JPanel` with `g.drawString(Str, int, int)`.

I am having trouble passing the specific random index of the array into the Str slot.

```
String[] messages = {"WOW, these fireworks are super cool.", "that one looks like a dragon", "did a star just explode","This would be cool on fourth of July.", "We should have packed a picnic"};

g.drawString(Arrays.toString(messages), getWidth()-300, (getHeight()/2)-200);
```

As of right now, this will print the entire array, I only want a specific randomized index. I was thinking about using something like this:

```
i=rand.nextInt(4);
messages[i];
```

I only want to print out `messages[i]`

Comment: Please add the code you already have.

Comment: since the code you are think of seems to be ok, why don´t you implement it? (you also would need to call `nextInt(5)` since it´s creating a number from `0-num-*1`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int i=new Random().nextInt(4);
String[] array={"Hello","Random Text","Apple","3.14159","Bye"};
g.drawString(array[i],300, 200);
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this :

```
String[] stringsData = new String[5];
[...]

Random random = new Random();
String randomString = stringsData[random.nextInt( stringsData.length )];
g.drawString(randomString, 0, 0);
```